# IE8 CSS higher specificity selector being ignored

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

I've got an IE8 specifity problem which is driving me nuts: http://proffetdemo.themesforge.com/shop/

The following selector is applied correctly in Chrome/Firefox et. al.

```
.tfshop-3 ul.products li.product {
    width: 30.5% !important;
}
```

But in IE8 it is completely ignored. The selector above is an override of another selector:

```
ul.products li.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 48%;
}
```

Anyone know why IE8 is ignoring the more specific selector?

**UPDATE 1: 15/02/13**
I now think this might be related to respond.js not loading correctly in IE8 - it looks like other media queries are not kicking in in IE8 - hmm...

Comment: You've got extra closing anchor tags with "tf_prodthumb_inner" which may be causing an issue.

Comment: @BillyMoat just spotted that issue - thanks for pointing it out - don't think it solves the IE8 issue though

Comment: @Mr.Alien not sure what you mean?

Comment: He means does the rule telling it to be 30.5% come after the ruling telling it to be 48%?

Comment: @BillyMoat- yes it does.

Comment: @BillyMoat Thanks for explaining, and Ed Bloom, are you are sure something else is not spcific? may be something more specific than there

Comment: @Mr.Alien - yes I'm sure - which is why i'm so perplexed by this!

Comment: just note if you add it as embed to anywhere on page that does fix, will play around with CSS for another 10 minutes to see what could be wrong here... looks weird but no wonder on IE

Comment: In your stylesheets you seem to have the 48% width declared first but you have the 30.5% width declared within a media query of (min-width: 768px). If that's the case then IE is behaving correctly and Firefox is wrong but I'm not sure why.

Comment: There are a number of [CSS errors](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fproffetdemo.themesforge.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fproffet%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en), some are innocuous like "Property zoom doesn't exist", but others may be affecting the parsing.

Comment: @BillyMoat - I thought you were on to something there but it IS picking up other selectors in that media query block like ul.products li.product.first {
  clear: both;
 }

Comment: @steveax I don't think it's the CSS errors but thanks for pointing them out :)

Answer (score 1):

try adding the tag in front of the class. like `div.tfshop ul.products li.product`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - I just tried that and it didn't make a difference to the IE8 problem

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
  div.tfshop-3 ul.products li.product {
    width: 30.5% !important;
}
  ...
}
```

you have these styles defined into @media conditional queries which is not supported by IE8 and lower http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

This is what http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ probably could help to deal with it in easier way.

Comment: thanks for your answer dmi3y but I'm using Respond.js which does enable media queries in IE8

Comment: yep, probably it acted up, because if you remove media query everything started to work magically ;)

Comment: but I need the selector to render a different width within that media query :)

Comment: that's another question, I am trying to help you to find out why it is not working, as it was asked 'IE8 CSS higher specificity selector being ignored'

Comment: yip fair point - I now think the issue might not be one of specificity but one related to media queries - thanks for your input!

Comment: yes, just guess, might the ~1700 lines of CSS code be reason for that, never had experience with respond.js before